# CSS Centering Rotated Text in a div

Tags: html, css, text, rotation

I am setting up a design that I have had passed to me.

The design requires a left aligned div (class=banner) to be placed right down the left hand side of the outer div.

This div is then to contain rotated text (-90deg) which needs to be centered and v-align middle within the div.

The issue is, this text can be of differing height and also differing length and font.

Is there a way that I can update my css to ensure the text always lands in the center of its parent div?

```
.banner
{
    height:90%; 
    width:5%;
    padding:5%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.rotated
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 2px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: -100%;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yz3jL58y/)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yz3jL58y/

Answer (score 2):

Just add:

```
display: flex;
justify-content:center;
```

to `#Ticket` property. 
https://jsfiddle.net/yz3jL58y/1/

Comment: I want the green banner to remain on the left, but want the 'New' (or whatever text) to be centered within the green area.

Comment: Thank you for your help Piotr.
The code works brilliantly - In Chrome.
BUT, I need to be able to produce using IE9 (as this is native for our project)
Everything works fine apart from the rotated text is not centered (top to bottom) in the banner (but it is in chrome) any ideas?